# How to Assign consistent Application ID to each application submitted against different offices

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

I have designed an application submission system for sub-offices of my company in asp.net. I am using a primary key as Appliaction No. but now I want to assign consistent application no to every sub office. I am using SQL Server for Database.

help me to tackle this problem.

Comment: Can you show you model ?

Comment: use a GUID............